# Whatsapp message not delivered before deleting account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I had sent a message to a friend of mine in WhatsApp. However, it could only reach the server (one tick). But owing to personal problems, I deleted my WhatsApp account before the message was delivered. Will the message still reach my friend?

Comment: I think it will, because once the message is on the server you cannot in any way stop it from being delivered, so it should be the same in your case.

Comment: But is there any hope for it to not be delivered? Because one can stop a message from being delivered even if it has reached the servers by simply blocking the person at least till the recipent comes online again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'll be delivered, because it's on the server. You cannot control it.

Comment: Would  you care to support your answer with something official or with technical sources? While your answer seems to be true at first glance, it may, in reality, be simply a speculation.